# Configuring ISP router (ZTE F660) in Bridge Mode

Tags: networking, router, bridge-router

My ISP provided me with the ZTE F660 for their fiber line. I am willing to use my own router (Archer C6) in bridge mode and install OpenWRT on it. I looked around in settings and found [this](https://i.ibb.co/Jd9LgVb/e1b85ccb-c440-4bbc-95a6-c232b8bb7b6c.jpg) in WAN config, so it looks like it does support bridge mode. Now my question is will I be able to use the IPTV and Landline normally with the ISP router once it is configured in the Bridge mode?

Comment: Probably not, confirm with your ISP

Comment: I did and they said they don't offer it. Is there anyway to get around this restriction somehow as the option to do it is available?

Comment: No, there isn't.